# position: absolute; bottom: 0; go to bottom of page

Tags: css, absolute

How do I make an absolutely positioned element go to the bottom of the page?

I want to create a "cover" over my page. In order to make it cover the whole page, I used "position: absolute" with each of the four directions set to 0. However, when the height of the page content is greater than the height of the client window, the cover height is the client height, not the height of the full page.

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/refipuyibu/edit?html,output)

```
<style>

#a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 2000px;
    background: red;
}

#b {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
}

</style>

<div id=a></div>

<div id=b></div>
```

I first tried to diagnose this issues as an issue of `<body></body>` height. Most issues like this step from the fact that the `<body></body>` does not extend to the bottom of the page. However, you'll notice that in this example the body actually **does** extend 2000px to the bottom of the page.

Note that `position: fixed` does not work because the user should still be able to scroll **and the content within the cover should scroll with the page**.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out!

You just needed the "containing block" of the element to be the body, so you just need to set `<body></body>` to be `position: relative`

Comment: Its funny how I mentioned that in my comment right now but didn't think of it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cover the full page just use `position: fixed`. That will keep the cover "fixed" to the viewport.

```
#cover {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that now the cover is no longer scrollable. I want the user to be able to scroll within the cover. All I want is the cover height to be the full 2000px body height.

Comment: @Will Okay so you want the cover to cover the entire body but want user to scroll it?

Comment: Exactly—the cover height should be 2000px, or whatever the height of the content is (we can't know this number beforehand), and it should scroll with the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` to always cover the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

The `position:fixed` does provide what you're looking for as you can see the contents are being scrolled down as you go. But what you're looking for, for the cover page to be over the entire height of the body without giving it a fixed height intitally, it can be only done through `javascript`.

```css
#a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 2000px;
  background: red;
}

#b {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id=a>
Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content Random content   
</div>

<div id=b></div>
```

Comment: It does **not** satisfy the question because content within `#b` does **not** scroll with the rest of the page. The **only** thing I'm looking to do is make an absolutely positioned element extend to the bottom of its container.

Comment: As I said, it can be done only through javascript if you don't want to set the overlay height initally. Do you want a javascript solution?

Comment: I guess the most helpful thing would be an explanation of how `position: absolute` works and why it does not align elements with their containers (as the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) seem to imply). It's surprising this is something CSS cannot support.

Comment: @Will Well, the absolute positioning refers to aligning the particular element to its absolute position with the pre-determined dimensions provided to it. It is always relative to its parent container, that's why its a good practice to generally make the parent container's position relative first. In this scenario, the position:absolute with top,bottom,left, right as '0' initally sets it to cover the entire width but the difference between absolute and fixed is seen here as, the scroll has no effect over fixed positioning and its fixed to the viewport, unlike absolute which gets affected.

Answer (score 0):

If your `<body>` is the final height that you want and you don't know the constraints, then I would set a `background-image` and let the browser calculate it:

```
body {
  background-image: url(/your/path/to/image.jpg);
  background-size: cover; /* This line is the magic. It fits the image to the size of the container, in this case, <body> */
  background-position: center;
}
```

This method will cut off any overflow. You can get around this by using `background-size: contain;`, however if the dimensions don't match, you'll also want to set a `background-color` to be sure it matches the site.

Comment: This method is only best if you don't want the image to skew, as would happen with setting the top, bottom, left and right of an absolutely positioned image (since the size of the body is bound to change shape depending on the viewport)

Comment: I just saw you are looking for it to start at the bottom of the screen. If so, `background-position: center bottom;`